# How to install applications under &HOME directory on Google Cloud Platform instance?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I set linux (ubuntu) instance on **Google Cloud Platform** and tried to install packages by using `apt-get` command, and I got direction below

```
username@name_of_instance-145302:~$ sudo apt-get install ssh
********************************************************************************
You are running apt-get tool inside of Cloud Shell. Note that your Cloud Shell  
machine is ephemeral and will be reset once you are not using it interactively  
for about half an hour.  No system-wide change will persist beyond that.        
Note that your home directory does persist across VM instantiations, so consider
installing your tools into your home directory whenever possible.               
To suppress this warning, create an empty ~/.cloudshell/no-apt-get-warning file.
The command will automatically proceed in 5 seconds or on any key. 
Visit https://cloud.google.com/shell/help for more information.                 
********************************************************************************
```

Maybe this warn shows that any files under the instance except `$HOME` directory will be cleared.
I want to save files under the `$HOME` directory, but downloaded packages are under the `/etc/package_name` - not under the `$HOME` directory.

So any applications downloaded from `apt-get` is deleted in 30 min after last operation.
How can I keep packages on `$HOME` directory?

Answer (score 4):

You tried to run apt-get from cloud shell not from your instance. you should ssh to your instance first. (one option is using "gcloud compute ssh "your instance name"), then you will be able to run apt-get.

Comment: Thank you, I could use `apt-get` after ssh to my instance. I should learn more about gcloud.